# Pass model to route to be populated by query parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am not sure how to explain this but I am trying to create a function to process app route. I want to pass in an object that will be populated by the fields in the request body. The code below give me an error req is not defined. This is a simplified version:

```
function getAction(data)
{
    app.get(data.path, (req, res) => {          
        getPerson(data.model, (err, person) => {
            return res.json(person);
        });
    }); 
}

getAction({
    path: "/getCustomer",
    model: {
            name: req.query.name,
            address: req.query.address
           }
});

getAction({
    path: "/getFriend",
    model: {
            name: req.query.name,
            sport: req.query.sport
           }
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is calling

http://host//getCustomer?name=bob&address=home

which would call the function getPerson("bob", "home")

http://host//getFriend?name=bob&sport=hockey

which would call the function getPerson("bob", "hockey")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `req` *is* not defined in those object literals you're passing to `getAction`. Pass functions instead:

```
function getAction(path, getModel) {
    app.get(data.path, (req, res, next) => {          
        getPerson(getModel(req), (err, person) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(person);
        });
    }); 
}

getAction("/getCustomer", req => ({
    name: req.query.name,
    address: req.query.address
}));

getAction("/getFriend", req => ({
    name: req.query.name,
    sport: req.query.sport
}));
```